# Ubuntu Crashes after random amount of time

Tags: 16.04, crash

So after a seemingly random amount of time, Ubuntu will crash, no error screen or anything, just black and unresponsive but the computer will remain on.
This is a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu, it doesn't seem to make a difference if its server or desktop.

System Specs:

```
AMD A10-6700 APU
Asus F2A55-M Mobo
8GB Ram
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

I didn't see anything of interest in the syslog but you guys are better at this than me so here that is:

https://pastebin.com/qxCHbVK0

Also I updated the bios to see if that made a difference (it didn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to be that guy but I solved my own problem.

The solution was to install a 3rd party driver (amd64-microcode) for AMD CPUs.
Since installing there have been no additional crashes.

Comment: It's not bad to solve your own problem. Neither is answering your own question. This site is a Q&A collection and you provided both Q and A. Nothing wrong with that. But you could ask yourself whether the question is of general interest and helpful to future readers.